# How to Use UIGesterRecognizer within Subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uislider

I have a subclass:

```
CustomView : UIScrollView.
```

Inside of this subclass I have some methods that, say, populate my custom view with some UI elements. I want to add UIGesterRecognizer functionality to these elements but I do not know how to handle setting the delegate and adding selectors:

```
@implementation  CustomView 

-populateMe{

     UIImageView *iv = [...];
     UIGesterRecognizer r = [UIGesterRecognizer alloc] 
          initWithTarget:self 
          action:@selector(handleMySwipe:); 
                          //<==where to declare handler

     r.delegate = self; //<==COMPILER ERROR self
     [iv.addGestureRecognizer r];
}
```

So my problem is where I commented above: self is not a valid delegate (I tried self.superclass) and where do I need to declare a handler for action, i.e. handleMySwipe.

Please explain so I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomView` *is* potentially a delegate, if you implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate) for it. That is, implement a few methods within your `CustomView` class that the protocol requires you to.

Once you've done that, you should be able to set the target parameter to `self` without any errors. Since your target is now `self`, you need to implement the selector/method `handleMySwipe:` *within* your `CustomView` class because that is where it will look for it (the target).

```
- (void) handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {
}
```